# How to connect Leshan Server to cloud (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, leshan

I am new to Leshan and was wondering if it was possible to send live data to AWS via AWS IOT's MQTT or AWS SDK? My main intention is to store sensor node data to AWS Database via Leshan.